# flutter stop in Compiling, linking and signing when building

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-run

i am trying to run my flutter project and it stuck in `Compiling, linking and signing...` when using `Flutter run --verbose`[image]

Comment: Have you add Crashlytics in your project?

Comment: @TwistedLullaby no, but is not crashing, is just stuck in that compiling linking

Comment: I mean, have you included Crashlytics lib in your project? Maybe post your dependencies list in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

There was some problem in `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`.

I resolved this problem like...

1. Create another flutter project.
2. Copy files in `ios/Runner.xcodeproj`.
3. Paste to the problematic project.
4. Fix `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and so on in `project.pbxproj` file.

Comment: is not working for me